# .NET Geolocation Library

Tags: .net, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, geospatial

I have a set of a few hundred UK locations specified by post code.  I need to find those within n miles of a given UK location.  I have google maps api so I can translate postcodes to long/lat coords.  I know the database platforms have various geospatial capabilities (MsSqlSpatial, PostGIS etc) but I would like to avoid anything platform specific as my app is currently DB agnostic (thanks to FluentNHibernate).

Is there an open source library that will enable me to query the dataset spatially in memory? The dataset will always be fairly small and all locations will be in the UK so perhaps I could use northings and eastings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small datasets, where you are not concerned with query performance and spatial indexing (i.e. full table scans are OK), just use the [Haversine formula](https://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/code-snippets/the-haversine-formula-in-c-and-sql/) to calculate distances between your location and postal codes.

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264944/point-on-circle-longitude-latitude-in-net-sql)

This does not use a .NET library but a SQL function. However, you could extract the mathematical formula to implement your own "point in circle" algorithm.

I adapted it to my needs some months ago and it perfectly works.